# Http error 500 with GWT web application

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty, mapdb

I've read tons of materials but I can't figure out what's happening. I'm doing a simple web application with Eclipse Oxygen, GWT 2.8, MapDB3, when I try to launch the web app through Run as -->  GWT development mode with Jetty I obtain the error above. I'm going mad.

Problem accessing /asteonlineing/greet. Reason:
    HTTP 500 Server Error
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics

```
at org.mapdb.DBMaker.fileDB(DBMaker.kt)
at com.google.asteonlineing.server.AoLServiceImpl.&lt;init&gt;(AoLServiceImpl.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [...a lot more]
```

I tried to add the kotlin's jar to my project's lib directory but the error slightly changes and it's alway http error 500 but about:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/collections/impl/list/mutable/primitive/LongArrayList

Finally I've figured out that MapDB 3.0.5 has a long list of dependencies.
I've installed all of them and that error disappeared but others are coming, but code related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out that MapDB 3.0.5 has a long list of dependencies, when I've installed all of them that error disappeared.
You can find them in
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapdb/mapdb/3.0.5